# text decoration underline for dom element doesn't underline for all letters in a word

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have used `text-decoration:underline` on an anchor tag. But the problem is it doesn't underline complete word, rather it underlines only selected letters.
Attached image.[image]

The font I am using is 'Gotham'. I tried to increase line height property, But that did not solve my problem. Did someone come across similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because the letters `p`, `y`, `g`, `j`, etc all have what are called [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). They will interrupt the flow of the underline and there isn't really anything to do about it. If you really want to have it under all of the text, I would suggest scrapping the `text-decoration` and using this:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This give the effect of the underline while still going under all of the letters.

Comment: Beat me by 53 seconds :-)

Comment: Yep. I'm fast on a keyboard :)

Comment: Solved my problem, But Still wondering why only in the mentioned font it behaves so. :)

Comment: Because that font has very "dangly" descenders. Other fonts don't have descenders that go so far down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is but if you are able to take a different approach, why not add this to the anchor tag instead?

```
a{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```